# Stock JDK classes and the "null" ClassLoader?

Tags: java, classloader

I am trying to debug a very strange class error by looking at the `ClassLoader`s for some dynamically created components. `ClassLoader`s are something I've never played much with - and im surprised that standard JDK classes have **null** Class loader instances.

Can somebody explain the output of this simple main method  in terms of the classes whose loaders I am attempting to print, and also more generally:

1. the way `ClassLoader`s work on the JVM and
2. how we can debug missing classes using `ClassLoader`s.

```java
public class MyClass {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println(relfect.MyClass.class.getClassLoader());
        System.out.println(String.class.getClassLoader());
        System.out.println(ArrayList.class.getClassLoader());
        System.out.println(JButton.class.getClassLoader());
        System.out.println(System.class.getClassLoader());

        Boolean b = new Boolean(true);
        System.out.println(b.getClass().getClassLoader());
        
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1f7182c1
null
null
null
null
null
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because StackOverflow is not a substitute for trivial JDK documentation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The javadoc for *`getClassLoader()`* says

> Returns the class loader for the class. Some implementations may use null to represent the bootstrap class loader. This method will return null in such implementations if this class was loaded by the bootstrap class loader.

So, that at least explains why you get that result. But it does not explain why the implementors decided to do it that way.

EDIT:
After testing adding my own classes to the bootclasspath then they also show up as null class loader.

Comment: Thanks , I was in the process of editing the question when you answered to clarify the more generic questions i have.  But in any case, your answer was helpful.

Comment: @jayunit100 Sorry ;-) But you can always post more questions.

Comment: This is old functionality.  I assume it is this way because "mistakes were made".  One possible reason for this may be that by returning null, the class does not need to store and/or track a class loader; it just implements the getClassLoader as `{ return null }`

Comment: hmmm... okay -- so how is it then that my class, from source code, is defaulted to the sun "App" ClassLoader ?

Comment: @jayunit100 Some class loader has to load your class, and if you haven't implemented it, someone must. Also, the null class loader seems to only be for bootstrap classes (typically the ones shipped with the JVM). It would be interesting to put your own class in the bootstrap and see what it reports.

Comment: @jayunit100 Just tried loading classes with the -Xbootclasspath/a and then they also report null as class loader.

Comment: @DwB, getClassLoader is native, and this - return null for the bootstrap is a security issue; i.e. it's not 'old functionality. it's designed to be like that.

Comment: @Roger, if you add class in the bootstrap path, its loader is null, mo magic whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

Classloader of the bootstrap classes is null, it's not a java class.

Do not mistake the classes found of the classpath and the ones loaded by the bootstrap loader. The latter is responsible for the core JDK classes usually found in rt.jar. It's a native classloader, hence no reference towards.

The classes on the classpath are loaded by the System classloader, and the class of it can be specified via property.

Morealso the null classloader is considered a security issue and there are checks based on the caller class having null classloader.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works . Whenever JVM try to load any class it's checks below conditions.

If Class is loaded from Bootstrap ClassPath i.e; jdk\jre\lib\rt.jar , BootStrap ClassLoader will be called.

If Class is loaded from Extension Classpath i.e; jdk\jre\lib\ext*.jar , Extension ClassLoader will be called.

If Class is loaded from Application ClassPath i.e; as specified in Environment Variable , Application ClassLoader is called .

Since Bootstrap ClassLoader is not implemented in java , it's either implemented in c or c++ so there is no reference for it that's why it returns null . But Extension and Application class Loader is written in java so you will get the reference as sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@someHexValue and sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@someHexValue .

So, if you do something like this System.out.println(String.class.getClassLoader()) you will get null since this class is been called by BootStrap ClassLoader, On the other hand if you do the same thing for a class in Ext or App Class path you will get $ExtClassLoader@someHexValue and sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@someHexValue respectively .