# Nullpointer when trying to get properties file

Tags: java

I have a maven project with the file `src/main/resources/barcoding.properties`. I keep getting a null pointer with the code below when trying to get the barcoding.properties file with the code below:

```
public class BarcodingProperties{
  private static Properties props = null;

  private static void getProperties() {
        System.out.println("we in getProperties");
        props = new Properties();
        InputStream in = BarcodingProperties.class.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("barcoding.properties"); <-- This line returns null pointer exception.
        System.out.println("in. = "+in.toString());
        try {
            props.load(in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("unable to load properties");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When i build the project and look into the jar file, barcoding.properties exists right in the project root.

Why does this return null and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the classloader of `Class` for loading the resource, instead of `BarcodingProperties` like this:

```
BarcodingProperties.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("barcoding.properties");
```

The `Class`'s classloader is null, indicating that it was loaded by the bootstrap class loader, see [Stock JDK classes and the "null" ClassLoader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450624/stock-jdk-classes-and-the-null-classloader) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

This seems strange:

```
BarcodingProperties.class.getClass()
```

BarcodingProperties.class is the BarcodingProperties class object instance. if you do a getClass() on that, it'll return the Class class object...

[Ideone fiddle](http://ideone.com/U89eoD) though with String.class

What you want is probably:

```
InputStream in = BarcodingProperties.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("barcoding.properties");
```